# Shutdown in RAC

Tags: oracle

If I use `sqlplus` in RAC environment and issue the command

```
shutdown immediate;
```

Does this shutdown the instance or all of them?

How does one prove the whole edifice is shutdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shutdown immediate` shuts down the current instance.

To shut down all RAC instances, issue the above shutdown command in all instances, or better use srvctl, for example:

```
srvctl stop database -d orcl
```